# Want to view images in sequence and delete

Tags: macos

I have downloaded photos to an iMac from camera into folders, not iPhoto.  I want to view the images on full screen in sequence and delete images as I go through them. I have come from Windows where there is a program that does that, but cannot find similar in the iMac.

Comment: what sequence, by name, date or ?

Answer (score 2):

I would (in Finder):

1) Switch to list view <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

2) Select the first picture in the list

3) hit <kbd>space</kbd> to activate Quick Look

4) if you want to delete the photo you are viewing hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>

5) otherwise hit the down arrow to go to the next picture

Comment: I tried it out, and you don't lose your place in the list.

Comment: (at least in Mavericks. I just noticed the mountain-lion tag)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Preview or [Sequential](http://sequentialx.com), you can press command-delete to move the current image to the trash.

I make HTML files for viewing images in Safari:

`for f in ~/Pictures/folder/*.jpg;do printf %s "<a href=$f><img src=$f height=469></a>";done>/tmp/a.html;open /tmp/a.html`

Then I for example open the files I want to delete in tabs and run a command like this:

`osascript -e 'set text item delimiters to linefeed' -e 'tell app "Safari" to URL of tabs of window 1 as text'|cut -d/ -f3-|xargs gmv -t ~/.Trash`

Comment: You can install Sequential using Terminal and [https://brew.sh/index_de](https://brew.sh/index_de) and `brew cask install sequential`.

Answer (score 0):

The application called Preview will do just that.

First in Finder sort the picture in order you want, like name, date, etc..

Select all pictures you want to see.

Double click to open in preview.

Now in Preview select Slide show (for full screen)

Press X to temporary exit full screen for deletion.

Now right click on the left side (icons preview) on the picture of choice to delete- Move to Trash.